# Somehow forum's got associated to wrong taxonomy vocabulary. Need help

Tags: nodes

I am using Advanced Forum 2.6 and I noticed that some of the views were set to pull the wrong vocabulary instead of the forum vocabulary. I set them all to pull the correct vocabulary but when I go to **/forum** the page title is still for the incorrect vocabulary and any change I make at **admin/structure/forum** also affects the terms in the previously connected vocabulary. It seems that the database is confused and I'm not sure how to reset things.

I am also getting a pair of the following errors for every term:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$num_topics in
>   mothership_preprocess_forum_list() (line 49 of
>   /Users/seankennedy/Documents/_IWS/drupal/sites/all/themes/mothership/mothership/functions/forum.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$num_topics in
>   mothership_preprocess_forum_list() (line 60 of
>   /Users/seankennedy/Documents/_IWS/drupal/sites/all/themes/mothership/mothership/functions/forum.php).

I am mostly a front end guy so I have little experience with messing around in the database directly but not afraid to have a go if that's what it will take to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

#### **Option 1**

Go to the Forum Topic manage fields and click edit in the forums field.

Check that the vocabulary is set to Forums

If it's not, delete the forum field and add the term reference field again.

[image]

[image]

#### **Option 2**

Have u posted content already to the forum? or do you care about the forum content? if not, **disabling and uninstalling** both Forum and Advanced Forum would be an option you could try and then enable them again.

Comment: Tried both options with no luck.

steps I took.
1. deleted term reference from forum topic
2. Created new term reference pointing to forum taxonomy
3. Disabled and Uninstalled both forum and advanced forum modules and cleared cache.
4. Re installed both modules and flushed cache. 

Result was no default forum taxonomy and Forum Topic content type pointing to the same incorrect taxonomy vocabulary as before. Same errors as above returned. One pair for each taxonomy term. The list of forums  has the default general forum but also has a mirror of the terms from the wrong taxonomy vocabulary.

Comment: Next I tried disable/uninstall and delete both forum and other tax vocabs. Now there is no config screen for Advanced forum and get error when going to a topic page

Notice: Array to string conversion in include() (line 36 of /Users/seankennedy/Documents/_IWS/drupal/sites/all/modules/contrib/advanced_forum/styles/naked/advanced-forum.naked.forums.tpl.php).